# Transform tuple type

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, metaprogramming

So I'm new to boost MPL, and I don't know how to use it with standard types.

I want a metafunction that coverts this type:

```
std::tuple<T0, T1, ..., TN>
```

Into this:

```
std::tuple<
  std::function<T0(std::tuple<T0, T1, ...>, std::tuple<T0, T1, ...>)>,
  std::function<T1(std::tuple<T0, T1, ...>, std::tuple<T0, T1, ...>)>,
  ...,
  std::function<TN(...)>
>
```

and it seems like this could be done with [transform](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/transform.html), but I want to have a tuple-type, not a vector of types. (It doesn't have to use MPL actually, but I guess it would be shorter?)

Background: currently I use totally generic types and rely on all hell breaking loose if used wrong, but I want to calculate the `TupleOfFunctions` to get a proper error.

```
template<class TupleOfValues, class TupleOfFunctions>
void f(TupleOfValues v, TupleOfFunctions fun)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the following?

```
template<typename T> struct transform;
template<typename ...T>
struct transform<std::tuple<T...>> {
  typedef std::tuple<std::function<T(std::tuple<T...>, std::tuple<T...>)>...> type;
};
```

Comment: It doesn't compile, but the form using the correct `std::function` syntax works: `std::tuple<std::function<T(std::tuple<T...>, std::tuple<T...>)>...>`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think `...` was so powerful, expected having to unroll it manually, nice. (could you fix the syntax though, I can't yet)