# Triangularizing a tuple

Tags: c++, c++17

I’ve been trying to upgrade (and slightly adapt) [this solution from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132487/transform-tuple-to-triangular-tuple) using modern features of C++.

My goal is actually slightly simpler than in that question; I’d like this:

```
triangularize_t<T0, T1, ..., TN-1, TN>
```

To be equivalent to this:

```
std::tuple<
  std::tuple<>,
  std::tuple<T0>,
  std::tuple<T0, T1>,
  ...
  std::tuple<T0, T1, ..., TN-1>
>
```

Such that `std::tuple_element_t<N, result>` has `N` elements. The type `TN` should not appear anywhere in the output.

Here’s what I’ve worked up to so far:

```
template <class _Tuple, class _Seq>
struct _tuple_head;
template <class _Tuple, size_t... _N>
struct _tuple_head<_Tuple, std::index_sequence<_N...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<_N, _Tuple>...>;
};


template <class _Tuple, class _Seq>
struct _triangularize_impl;
template <class _Tuple, size_t... _N>
struct _triangularize_impl<_Tuple, std::index_sequence<_N...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<typename _tuple_head<_Tuple, std::make_index_sequence<_N>>::type...>;
};


template <class... _Pack>
struct triangularize {
    using type = _triangularize_impl<std::tuple<_Pack...>, std::index_sequence_for<_Pack...>>;
};


template <class... _Pack>
using triangularize_t = typename triangularize<_Pack...>::type;
```

However, it doesn’t quite seem to be expanding the way I’d expect it to.  Using `triangularize_t<int, float>` as a test, error messages seem to report that the output for `std::get<0>` and `1` return these types (identical for some reason).

```
_triangularize_impl<tuple<std::__1::tuple<int, float> >, __make_integer_seq<integer_sequence, unsigned long, 1UL> >

_triangularize_impl<tuple<std::__1::tuple<int, float> >, __make_integer_seq<integer_sequence, unsigned long, 1UL> >
```

What have I missed here?

Comment: Don't use identifiers that start with underscore followed by an uppercase letter. These are reserved for the implementation in all contexts (in particular, they could be `#define`-d).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe someone can make it in a simpler way... but what about as follows?

```
template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
auto gtt_helper (std::index_sequence<Is...>)
 -> std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<Is, T>...>;

template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
auto getTriTuple (std::index_sequence<Is...>)
 -> std::tuple<decltype(gtt_helper<std::tuple<Ts...>>
                        (std::make_index_sequence<Is>{}))...>;

template <typename ... Ts>
using triTuple
  = decltype(getTriTuple<Ts...>(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}));
```

The following is a full compiling C++14 example

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
auto gtt_helper (std::index_sequence<Is...>)
 -> std::tuple<std::tuple_element_t<Is, T>...>;

template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
auto getTriTuple (std::index_sequence<Is...>)
 -> std::tuple<decltype(gtt_helper<std::tuple<Ts...>>
                        (std::make_index_sequence<Is>{}))...>;

template <typename ... Ts>
using triTuple
  = decltype(getTriTuple<Ts...>(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}));

int main () 
 {
   using T0 = triTuple<char, int, long, long long>;
   using T1 = std::tuple<std::tuple<>,
                         std::tuple<char>,
                         std::tuple<char, int>,
                         std::tuple<char, int, long>>;

   static_assert( std::is_same<T0, T1>::value, "!" );
 }
```

To respond to your question ("What have I missed here?"), you have missed a `typename` and a `::type` in `triangularize`

It seems to me that the right version should be

```
template <class... _Pack>
struct triangularize {
// ..........VVVVVVVV  add typename
using type = typename _triangularize_impl<std::tuple<_Pack...>,
                                          std::index_sequence_for<_Pack...>>::type ;
// and add ::type ..........................................................^^^^^^
};
```

Unfortunately, your (corrected) code seems to works with clang++ but not with g++; I suspect a g++ bug but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think this might be the cleanest solution using only the STL. Still kicking myself for missing that last `::type`, but then I never thought of using `decltype` for this. I’m going to have to go away and experiment some more with `decltype`!

Comment: @MTCoster - yes, `decltype()` is very useful in this sort of problems.

Answer (score 3):

With [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html) this is... unfortunately not a one-liner. It takes a couple lines instead.

We define one function to perform a single action: given a list of everything and the next element, append that one (that is, this takes us from the `N`th solution to the `N+1`st solution):

```
template <typename L, typename T>
using add_one = mp_push_back<L, mp_push_back<mp_back<L>, T>>;
```

And now fold over that - which just applies that binary function for each argument in turn:

```
template <typename... Ts>
using triangularize_t = mp_fold<mp_list<Ts...>, tuple<tuple<>>, add_one>;
```

And check that it's [correct](https://godbolt.org/z/3EYmZF):

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<triangularize_t<>,
    tuple<tuple<>>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<triangularize_t<int>,
    tuple<tuple<>, tuple<int>>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<triangularize_t<int, char>,
    tuple<tuple<>, tuple<int>, tuple<int, char>>>);
```

---

We can generalize this to work on *any* class template instead of *solely* tuple by changing `triangularize` to use an input list and deduce its initial value from the input argument:

```
template <typename L>
using triangularize_t = mp_fold<L, mp_push_back<mp_clear<L>, mp_clear<L>>, add_one>;
```

Which also [allows](https://godbolt.org/z/aEkS6j):

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<triangularize_t<mp_list<int, char>>,
    mp_list<mp_list<>, mp_list<int>, mp_list<int, char>>>);
```

Or whatever other lists you might want to use (notably not `variant`, since `variant<>` is ill-formed).

Comment: The OP wants the last template argument to be unused. e.g. `triangularize_t<int, char>` is `tuple<tuple<>, tuple<int>>`.

Comment: @aschepler That's kinda weird, to pass in an argument that's never used. Why not just make `triangularize_t<int>` do that? But anyway, that's an easy fix - we can  `mp_pop_back` the initial list (or the result).

Comment: @aschepler Added a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59109096/2069064) that does that - this time actually as a one liner :-)

Comment: @Barry wow, nice... but according to [origin solution](https://godbolt.org/z/vYjKHm), could you tell me which compiler I should believe?

Comment: @康桓瑋 clang is correct. There is a pack there to expand, gcc just doesn't see it.

Answer (score 2):

With [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html) this is a one-liner. I just didn't try hard enough last time. Also this solution matches OP's exact specification:

```
template <typename... Ts>
using triangularize_t =
    mp_transform_q<
        mp_bind_front<mp_take, std::tuple<Ts...>>,
        mp_rename<mp_iota_c<sizeof...(Ts)>, std::tuple>
        >;
```

Lemme explain what this does, assuming `Ts...` is `<int, char>`.

- `mp_iota_c<sizeof...(Ts)>` gives the sequence `mp_list<mp_int<0>, mp_int<1>>`.
- `mp_rename` swaps out one "list" type for another, in this case `mp_list` for `std::tuple` so you get `std::tuple<mp_int<0>, mp_int<1>>`.
- `mp_bind_front<mp_take, std::tuple<Ts...>>` creates a metafunction on the fly that will take an argument and apply it to `mp_take` on the full `tuple<Ts...>`. `mp_take` takes the first `N` things from the given list. If we passed in `mp_int<1>` to this, on our initial `tuple<int, char>`, we'd get `tuple<int>`.
- `mp_transform_q` calls the provided metafunction on each element in the list. We take our `tuple<mp_int<0>, mp_int<1>>` and expand it out into `tuple<mp_take<tuple<int, char>, mp_int<0>>, mp_take<tuple<int, char>, mp_int<1>>>` which is `tuple<tuple<>, tuple<int>>`. As desired.

---

To change this into my other answer (which triangularizes `<int>` into `tuple<tuple<>, tuple<int>>`), we can change `sizeof...(Ts)` into `sizeof...(Ts)+1`.

To extend this to support *any* list type (not just `tuple`), we can change the metafunction here to take a list instead of a pack and use the provided list type as a solution. In some respects, this makes the solution easier:

```
template <typename L>
using triangularize_t =
    mp_transform_q<
        mp_bind_front<mp_take, L>,
        mp_append<mp_clear<L>, mp_iota<mp_size<L>>>
        >;

template <typename... Ts>
using triangularize_t = triangularize_list<std::tuple<Ts...>>;
```

The awkward part here is the `mp_append<mp_clear<L>, mp_iota<mp_size<L>>>`. Basically, we need the sequence list to have the same list type as the original list. Before, we could use `mp_rename` because we know we needed a tuple. But now, we don't have the list as a class template - just have an instance of it. There might be a better way to do this than `mp_append<mp_clear<L>, U>`... but this is what I have so far.

Comment: Wow, this is impressive! I’ve accepted max66’s answer because I didn’t want to add a dependency on this project, but given how powerful Boost.Mp11 is looking I’ll definitely check it out for future use.

Comment: @MTCoster Mp11 is awesome, I think it's the best metaprogramming library. If you're at all skeptical, I have a lot of other answers on here that solve all sorts of problems with a "With Mp11, this is a one-liner" answer. Can't speak of it highly enough. (And if you're concerned about Boost as a whole for whatever reason, you can get Mp11 standalone.)

Answer (score 1):

We can avoid having to use any `index_sequence`s by utilizing partial specialization with multiple parameter packs.

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename Tuple, typename LastTuple, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct triangulate;

template <typename Tuple, typename LastTuple, typename Last>
struct triangulate<Tuple, LastTuple, Last> {
    using type = Tuple;
};

template <typename First, typename Second, typename... TupleTypes, typename... LastTupleTypes, typename... Rest>
struct triangulate<std::tuple<TupleTypes...>, std::tuple<LastTupleTypes...>, First, Second, Rest...> {
    using next = std::tuple<LastTupleTypes..., First>;
    using type = typename triangulate<std::tuple<TupleTypes..., next>, next, Second, Rest...>::type;
};

template <typename... T>
using triangularize_t = typename triangulate<std::tuple<std::tuple<>>, std::tuple<>, T...>::type;
```

Passing the end product as the first parameter (`std::tuple<std::tuples...>>`), and the second parameter is the last `std::tuple<...>` we used.

We then recursively add the next parameter to the last tuple, and add that tuple to the end of the end-result.